# Why my jquery isn't displayed by browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i am new to jq and i am trying to run this code but the browser doesn't show anything, tried to link the script library before ending tag of body.
Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
enter code here
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Data Types</title>
    <script src="jq/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    document.write(3.25 + 1000);
    document.write('<br>' + 5 - 1000);

    var1 = "Buna";
    var2 = "Ziua";
    document.write("<br>Concatenare siruri:" + var1 + var2 + '<br>');

    a = true;
    document.write(a);
    var = fructe['mere', 'pere', 'caise'];
    document.write('<br>' + fructe[1]);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: See [ask] and make sure you take the [tour]. The idea is that you tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and say what results you got. Everything should be in the question as text, including your [mcve] and any error messages. In this case it seems like you could spend a little time in the "developer" view of your favourite browser and get a lot more useful information. Even if this doesn't help you now, it may result in information you can use here in this question.

Comment: This is clearly a typo problem (you should check developers tools console or use a proper IDE). Also you have jquery in title and tag but you're showing vanilla JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix this line:

```
var = fructe['mere', 'pere', 'caise'];
```

To

```
var fructe = ['mere', 'pere', 'caise'];
```